# what is the disadvantage of vector over arraylist in collection and why?

Tags: vector, collections, arraylist

i am unable to understand what is the actual concept behind synchronization that is used in vector class please answer.

Because yesterday, i used a vector which is much better than array list. So here i am little bit confused.

```
import java.util.Vector;    

public class VectorExample {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Vector<String> vc=new Vector<String>();    

        //    <E> Element type of Vector e.g. String, Integer, Object ...    

        // add vector elements    
        vc.add("Vector Object 1");    
        vc.add("Vector Object 2");    
        vc.add("Vector Object 3");    
        vc.add("Vector Object 4");   
        vc.add("Vector Object 5");    

        // add vector element at index    
        vc.add(3, "Element at fix position");   

        // vc.size() inform number of elements in Vector    
        System.out.println("Vector Size :"+vc.size());    

        // get elements of Vector     
        for(int i=0;i<vc.size();i++)    
        {   
            System.out.println("Vector Element "+i+" :"+vc.get(i));    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: "Because yesterday, i used a vector which is much better than array list." What do you mean, how is it better?

Comment: basically i am new in java and i need explanation thats why i am asking this question.

Comment: But you say Vector is much better than ArrayList yourself, why? How is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As you know Vector is a grandPa of ArrayList and is there since JDK 1.0.

If you read JavaDoc, Java itself recommends restricted use of Vector

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to
>   implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java
>   Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations,
>   Vector is synchronized. **If a thread-safe implementation is not needed,
>   it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector**.

Answer (score 0):

Internal implementation ArrayList & Vector are same. Both are used array to data in back end.

All the public methods are synchronized. So Performance wise its slow. Its a very old implementation.

Apart that `setSize` method available in Vector.

As per JavaDoc

```
Sets the size of this vector. If the new size is greater than the current size, new null items are added to the end of the vector. If the new size is less than the current size, all components at index newSize and greater are discarded.
```